# "define:" oneboxing is still not quite ok

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

So, apparently the wiktionary oneboxing feature had a little makeover and now it doesn't just onebox into some ugly dump straight from the page.

[image: they didn't]

Except when it does. As you can see, "they" expanded into the garbage format, while the rest was ok.

Comment: If by "it was ok" you mean "it took up huge quantities of room"